# Success message after completion jsonfile npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I'm writing a small application that stores users and a link in a json file.

```
    var response = saveUser(user,steamLink);
    sendMessages(channelID,[response]);
```

Basically I am able to write to the file, i just need to set the message variable as soon as it's completed.

```
        function saveUser(userId, steamProfile,channelID){
         var userList;
         var message;
         var file = "db/db.json";
         var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file,'utf8'));
         var userList = obj;
         if(_.find(userList.users,['userId',userId])){
            message = 'This user allready has a steamlink';
         }else{
           var temp = new Object();
           temp['userId'] = userId;
           temp['steamLink'] = steamProfile;    
           userList.users.push(temp);
           var obj = userList;
           jsonfile.writeFile(file,obj,function(err,message){
            if(!err){
             message = "Member Added";
            } 
           });
          console.log(transfer);
        }
        return message;
        }
```

Excuse my indentation, I can't seem to be able to paste it the way it was well formatted !

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be asynchronous also:

```
function saveUser(userId, steamProfile,channelID, callback) {
    ...
    jsonfile.writeFile(file,obj,function(err,message) {
        if(!err){
            message = "Member Added";
            callback(message);
        } 
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the place, where it was called from:

```
saveUser(userId, steamProfile, channelID, function (message) {
    console.log(message); 
});
```